# Adding model to database that has virtual relations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this scenario where i have a model named Category that has a One-To-One relation with another model named Question. The following is the code for both of the models:

Category:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int QuestionRef { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

Question:

```
public class Question
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryRef { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int QuestionLevel { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Snippet from OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasOne(x => x.Question).WithOne(x => x.Category).HasForeignKey<Question>(x => x.CategoryRef);
modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().HasOne(x => x.Category).WithOne(x => x.Question).HasForeignKey<Category>(x => x.QuestionRef);
```

I seem to have come across a problem that i cannot understand how to tackle. Basically, i do not have a clue of how i can insert this relation into the database (SQL Server).

The question is do i have to implicitly write in the repository that

```
NewCategory.Question = QuestionInput;
```

or does it automatically generate itself given the relations i have implied in the OnModelCreating?

Comment: A category is generally defined as a grouping of items. I don't quite see how this would need to be a one-to-one relationship. Are you sure you need a one-to-one? Just trying to make sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: in my solution i made it that i have multiple Categories but every Question has only one question. I have also omitted a large chunk of the other models present in my system. Namely, a Question must have one or more Answers, these Answers can have no or one more Question, but i didn't want to make this question a bit too overbearing. The models themselves aren't the problem its the way i have to do the back-end processes that is confusing me